# Issue in creating link <name>.domain.com

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, web

I have created a asp.net web application (matchstreak.com). I want to rewrite the URL as payslip.matchstreak.com. I haven't done this before and I have no knowledge on how to do it. Can someone please help me out with this ?

Comment: You can Make subdomain from your websitePanel then redirect it to your main domain.

Comment: Could you please tell an example ?

Answer (score 0):

Simply add one simple html page in your subdomain (payslip.matchstreak.com) which redirect your url to matchstreak.com